Session Cookie Set But Not Sent in Subsequent Requests in a NestJS-React App
I'm developing a web application with a React frontend and a NestJS backend, using GitHub OAuth for authentication. The authentication flow successfully sets a session cookie when the user logs in, but subsequent requests do not include this cookie, despite being set with the correct attributes. This issue occurs only in the production environment; everything works as expected locally.
Frontend: deployed on vercel
Backend: deployed on fly.io
Implementation:

The user initiates the GitHub OAuth flow and is redirected back to the /auth/github/callback endpoint on the backend with an auth code.
The backend exchanges the code for a GitHub token, retrieves the user profile, creates a session, and sets a sessionId cookie.
The sessionId cookie is configured with HttpOnly, Secure, and SameSite=None attributes.
CORS is configured on the backend to accept requests from the frontend domain

Code Snippets:
Setting the cookie in NestJS (backend):
 const expiresCurrentTimeZone = new Date();
      expiresCurrentTimeZone.setUTCMonth(
        expiresCurrentTimeZone.getUTCMonth() + 1,
      );
      res.cookie("sessionId", session._id.toString(), {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        expires: expiresCurrentTimeZone,
        path: "/",
      });

Fetching route in react:
const response = await fetch(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/session/validateSession`,
          {
            credentials: "include",
          },
        )

Server:
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
import * as cors from "cors";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  const clientUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_URL

  const options = {
    origin: clientUrl, // Use the environment variable value here.
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  };

  app.use(cors(options));

  app.use(cookieParser());
  await app.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
}
bootstrap();


What I've tried:

Confirmed that the frontend request to the protected route includes credentials: 'include'.
Verified that the sessionId cookie has the correct domain, path, and is visible in the browser's cookie storage.
Checked CORS configuration on the backend to ensure it allows credentials and sets the correct Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Problem:
After the sessionId cookie is set by the backend, it's visible in the browser's storage, but it's not included in subsequent requests to the backend, leading to a 401 Unauthorized error for routes requiring authentication.

What is the value of clientUrl? Does it contain a path?

@jub0bs Hi, thanks for the reply! Forgot to paste that in my body but I've added it above - it goes to NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_URL (frontend url)

You're not answering my question, though. :)

@jub0bs whoops! It doesn't contain a path, its just the domain name for the homepage

Does it contain a scheme/protocol? Does it start with https://?

@jub0bs yeah it does start with https://

If anyone runs into this issue, it turns out firefox/chrome/safari were preventing cookies from sending because they were being flagged as 3rd party cookies. I had to set the fly.io subdomain to match the FE
